# This is related to licensing issue. Can following ASP.NET MVC related assemblies be distributed freely with ASP.NET MVC applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While working on an ASP.NET MVC based application I bumped into this question that if the following assemblies be distributed freely with the ASP.NET MVC based application:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Http.dll
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
System.Web.WebPages.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
```

These assemblies are in my \bin folder.

Comment: Yes, they are open source. Check http://www.asp.net/mvc/open-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dlls mentioned above are licensed under Microsoft distribution policy.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetmvc3update-eula.htm

The eula file you can find on the machine where you installed Visual Studio 2012. It’s for licensing of MVC4 assemblies:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\eula.rtf